# Angular JS multiple get requests in a single controller

Tags: angularjs

I have an app module and app controller. when I try using a single get request the result displays but when I try to do one more get request then I guess there is a problem.

```
var app = angular.module('bizapp', []);

app.controller('landcont', function($location, $scope, $http, $window){

$scope.user = $location.search().username;

 **//This one works. result comes.**

  $http({
        method  : "GET",
        url     : "webapi/company/apps"
      }).then(function mySucces(response) {

          $scope.records= response.data;

          }, function myError(response) {
          $scope.apps= response.statusText;
      });


  $scope.redir=function(event){       

   **//This one doesnot work. no result comes.**

      $http({
            method  : "GET",
            url     : "webapi/login/usermap"
          }).then(function mySuccesss(res) {

                alert(res);
          } 

      var uri= 'http://localhost:8080/bizlms/bizint.php?app='+event.target.id;//+encodeURIComponent(query);

      $window.open(uri, "_self");
  }`
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: The second `$http` call is in a function called `$scope.redir`, if you don't run that function then it won't run your `$http` request!

Comment: i know that @MatthewCawley...i am actually calling this function on a click event...second http doesnot work...

Comment: Okay sorry, don't want to overlook the 'obvious'. You also appear to be missing a closing `)` bracket to the second `$http` promise's `then` function call.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `$http` call runs when your controller defined. The second one is within a function. Just defining the function `redir` on $scope does not mean it is executed. In your template you can use.

```
<span ng-click="redir()">click me</span>
```

Comment: Actually, I am calling the $scope.redir on a click event. The function is executing..say..`$scope.redir= function(event){ alert("hi")}` works...but as you can see in the code, I have alerted the result of the second HTTP call...thats where i have a problem.

Comment: is there anything like mutliple http calls does not work on one single controller or something like that?

Comment: maybe the http request fails. try to alert/console.log() something on error too and watch the network tab in your developer tools

Answer (score 0):

Add a closing `)` bracket to the second `$http` promise's `then` function call:

```
$http({
    method  : "GET",
    url     : "webapi/login/usermap"
})
.then(function(res) {
    alert(res);
}); // <----------- Add closing ")" here
```

Also note that I've taken the name of function `mySuccesss` out because it's not needed. The first function to be passed in to the promise's `then` function will always be the used as the success callback function. Unless you're using the function name elsewhere, then it's not really needed. You could argue that it names the function and tells the reader that it's the "success" function callback, but the code is already telling you that - by passing it in as the first parameter.